# Accuracy assessment on multiple classified images

Tags: accuracy, accuracy-assessment

I am attempting to compare the accuracy of multiple different classified images I have created from a single raster. Basically, I want to avoid having to input 'ground truth' values for each accuracy assessment I perform on each classified image.

Is there a way to create the same accuracy assessment points for multiple classified images having the same 'ground truth' values applicable to each accuracy assessment?